# Из обычной БД сделать распределенную

Tags: delphi, база-данных, firebird, interbase

Есть обычная БД на Firebird и клиенты (к ней), я хочу ее сделать распределенной.
Насколько это cложно? Или лучше начать все сначала?

Я никогда с распределенными БД дел не имел. Т.е.:

```
 - создал три БД
 - в них создал по таблице
```

теперь их нужно связать? А через что? Или как это делается?

Comment: Вы лучше расскажите подробнее, чего вы вообще хотите добиться, для чего вам это.

Answer (score 2):

А что в Вашем понятии распределенная ?
Создали три БД, ну теперь создайте что-то центральное, что будет к ним обращаться и взаимодействовать между ними. А к этому центральному уже будет обращаться ПО пользователя.

Суть распределенной БД состоит в том, что базы как правило разбросаны по разным вычислительным машинам, и существует центральный запущенный процесс, который слушает клиента и отправляет соответствующие команды на соответствующий комп для обработки информации и получения набора данных. Что позволяет при огромных объемах, вычислять данные на разных вычислительных ресурсах и возвращать обратно клиенту лишь ответ.